# Controlling ALT Key with Silverlight control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, internet-explorer

We are working on a project right now that calls to have a view of the same control for both a Desktop client and the Web client. We are using WPF and Silverlight to cover both needs. On the Desktop application with the WPF control we use the "Alt" key modifier to execute a specific task inside the control with the mouse. We are implementing the same functionality in Silverlight and we now found that Iternet Explorer uses that same key to show the menu bar and the status bar... so, basically we have this odd behavior when our clients use the Alt-mouse. So, my question is, how can I handle the Alt event in IE so it does not happen but that our own event kicks in without showing the menu bar first??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Keys are first handled by the browser itself and then passed onto the Silverlight control. So short of changing the standard behaviour of IE you can't do anything.

I see two solutions:

1. Use a different key. Not ideal and will probably cause some confusion, but you are running a web application and your users should expect it to behave differently to a desktop one.
2. Make your Silverlight application an [Out of Browser application.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This runs the application outside the browser, but still in a sandbox and will update etc. as would an in-browser application, but there's no browser to swallow key presses so you can use the `Alt` key the same as you would for a desktop application.

Comment: Gee, well if there is absolutely no way, I guess it may have to be the first option.

Answer (score 0):

What you wanna do is the following (**Im not sure if this will hide the menu or not**)

- Capture Alt Key (in JavaScript make sure you add JQuery)
- Focus the Silverlight host
- Call C# method

#### Capture alt

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slHost = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        slHost = $('#silverlightControlHost'); // Caches Silverlight Host find the div id that holds the silverlight object tag
    });

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.altKey) {
            focus();
            if (slHost)
                slHost.Content.ScriptableObjectNameThatsBelow.MethodNameInClass();
        }
    });  
</script>
```

#### Call C# from JS

```
[ScriptableType] //Attribute above class

HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Name of Class or whatever", this); // Add to constructor

[ScriptableMember] // Attribute above method
```